# Packaging dependencies inside electron app

Tags: electron, sox, electron-packager

My `electron` app for Mac OSX has `sox` dependency. What's the best way to include it as part of `electron-package`? I'd prefer the user not having to install sox separately (unfortunately most of my users are not that savy). Is there a way to include sox binaries directly or sequence pre-install of sox before my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up including the sox binary into the package. I used `node-record-lpcm16` package and updated its path to use included sox binary. This way I can pass down the the lib path as a parameter.

Comment: Great answer! I was wondering, how did you update the path of the package? I added the sox folder to the package, and updated the `index.js` file, but I was wondering if you achieved a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

That's right using binary is the safest way.

**How to add binary files into an Electron app?**

It should be done by the [package](https://www.electronforge.io/core-concepts/build-lifecycle#step-1-package) step in this way.

**Steps**:

1. Download the [binary version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.4.2/) for any target platform, unzip it, and put it in your project root as `sox` directory. create `mac,linux,win32` folders if you want as subdirectories.
2. Tell the packager module to include the `sox` directory. the sox dir will copied into `Contents/Resources` of the app based on the target platform.

```js
// Assuming you use electron forge, 
// and this is the config file
const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {
    extraResource: [
      // Sox binaries for recording audio
      join(__dirname, "sox"),
    ],
  },
}
```

3. Find the `sox` directory on runtime by `process.resourcesPath` and use it as you want.

```js
// Inside the main trade
import { tmpdir, platform } from "os";

function getSoxPath() {

  switch (platform()) {
    case "darwin":
      return join(process.resourcesPath, "sox", "mac");
    case "win32":
      return join(process.resourcesPath, "sox", "win32");
    case "linux":
      return join(process.resourcesPath, "sox", "linux");
    default:
      throw new Error("Unsupported platform");
  }

}
```

4. Now, you can open a child process and use `sox` directly, or use this forked `node-record-lpcm16` library that has `recorderPath` for introducing `sox` path.

```js
// To Install 
// yarn add https://github.com/navidshad/node-record-lpcm16

// To use
import recorder from "node-record-lpcm16";

recorder.record({
  recorder: "sox",
  recorderPath: getSoxPath(),
});
```